# How do I display ► Play (Forward) or Solid right arrow symbol in html?

Tags: html, ascii

How do I display this ► Play (Forward) or Solid right arrow symbol in html?

Comment: Is there something like &play; I can use?

Comment: Just for guys who need the other directions too:
▲ &#9650;
► &#9658;
▼ &#9660;
◄ &#9668;

Comment: How do you show it in JavaScript ?

Comment: Another character is this: ▶, given by `&#9654;`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Yes, `&#9658;`, but it might not look the same in all browsers.

Comment: Characters should not be expected to look the same, but this character, BLACK RIGHT-POINTING POINTER (U+25BA), is of simple shape, and font designers have little reason to do anything exotic with it. It has good font coverage, including very common fonts like Arial: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25ba/fontsupport.htm

Comment: Just to clarify: &#9658; is equivalent to (U+25BA)

Comment: Be careful, everyone. 25BA looks squished on some devices because it's a "pointer" and not a "triangle." If you're looking for an equilateral triangle, use 25B6. Here's a chart: http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp

Comment: Is there any code for back button I am using the above code as forward button as &#9658 + | ?

Answer (score 38):

If you need to use it in CSS, as in

```
    li:before {
        content: '\25BA';
    }
```

This is the CSS conversion of `&#9658;`
A helpful tool for these conversions: [evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html](http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html)

Comment: You got a type there, it should be `content:'\25BA';` and not `content='\25BA';`

Comment: evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html is awesome.

Answer (score 33):

`&#9658;` from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%96%BA)

Comment: Holy cow. I logged in to say thanks for teaching me this about wolfram alpha.

Comment: Regarding the suggested edit (I don't have enough reputation to reject it): The point is that you can paste the symbol into WolframAlpha and don't need to know the HTML representation. The form in which I posted was fully intentional. Please revert to the original version.

Comment: Here's all the other symbols http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characters+9632+through+9727&lk=1

Answer (score 12):

I tried using the ascii code but didn't like it as it always looked stretched.

Instead, I found an ingenious easily customizable solution online, that uses css and only manipulates the border property:

```css
.play {
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
  border-left: 20px solid black;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="play"></div>
```

Comment: worth noting that you can use `transparent` as a color option

Comment: also this codepen is crucial for explaining how this works: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lotjh

Answer (score 11):

Here's a long list of what you can use:

http://brucejohnson.ca/SpecialCharacters.html

Comment: Yes it is, under Unclassified Characters (http://brucejohnson.ca/SpecialCharacters.html#unclassified).

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap glyphicons is a reliable library for icons:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><br>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span><br>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><br>
```

Remember to also include Bootstrap and jQuery in the `<head>` element.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

JSFiddle explaining this: https://jsfiddle.net/canada/dfr90pac/

Answer (score -9):

Well, you could use an image and display it in the `<img>` tags. On their click event, you could write some JavaScript code. You could search the images in Google.

Comment: There is no `</img>` closing tag.